# Most compact solution for external monitor for 2011 MacBook Pro

Tags: gpu, hardware-recommendation, hacking

My MacBook Pro's dGPU failed and I did the software "fix" where I am forcing the use of the integrated GPU. Unfortunately because of disabling the dGPU there is no way to connect the external monitor to the thunderbolt because it's wired through the dGPU.

Short of replacing/repairing my motherboard what are my options to add an external monitor? Here are my requirements:

1. I am willing to buy a really compact external gpu. But which one?
2. I am willing to hack my MacBook Pro, for example to add one in the CD drive slot, assuming such a hack even exists.

EDIT: 
Here is an additional requirement: I use the external monitor for doing text editors and development most of the times and the occasional movie. No gaming at all.

----------Config--------------

```
  Model Name:   MacBook Pro
  Model Identifier: MacBookPro8,2
  Processor Name:   Intel Core i7
  Processor Speed:  2.2 GHz
  Number of Processors: 1
  Total Number of Cores:    4
  L2 Cache (per Core):  256 KB
  L3 Cache: 6 MB
  Memory:   16 GB
  Boot ROM Version: MBP81.004F.B00
  SMC Version (system): 1.69f3

Intel HD Graphics 3000:

  Chipset Model:    Intel HD Graphics 3000
  Type: GPU
  Bus:  Built-In
  VRAM (Dynamic, Max):  512 MB
  Vendor:   Intel (0x8086)
  Device ID:    0x0126
  Revision ID:  0x0009
  gMux Version: 1.9.23
```

Answer (score 1):

I purchased a Wavlink 2.0 USB to HDMI/DVI adapter and its working fine as of now with my MBP. Text editing and movie watching have not been an issue.

My monitor is an old HP 2311x. YMMV on different more high res monitors? I had to install their software for my macosx to get it to work which was not so hard.

There are some [wonderful details](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/fb/udlfb.txt) about this technology.